# Always show photos from camera first

Tags: android, camera, cursor, photos

I have a CursorLoader for loading photos to choose from:

```
    public class PhotoDirectoryLoader extends CursorLoader {
      final String[] IMAGE_PROJECTION = {
      Media._ID,
      Media.DATA,
      Media.BUCKET_ID,
      Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
      Media.DATE_ADDED,
          Media.TITLE
      };

  public PhotoDirectoryLoader(Context context, boolean showGif) {
    super(context);

    setProjection(IMAGE_PROJECTION);
    setUri(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    setSortOrder(Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

    setSelection(
        MIME_TYPE + "=? or " + MIME_TYPE + "=? or "+ MIME_TYPE + "=? " + (showGif ? ("or " + MIME_TYPE + "=?") : ""));
    String[] selectionArgs;
    if (showGif) {
      selectionArgs = new String[] { "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg","image/gif" };
    } else {
      selectionArgs = new String[] { "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg" };
    }
    setSelectionArgs(selectionArgs);
  }


  private PhotoDirectoryLoader(Context context, Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                               String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    super(context, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
  }


}
```

Problem is, that if I take picture on camera, I see photos from camera at the top of the list. But when I take screenshot, screenshots jump up above photos from camera and I'd like to keep photos from camera always on top.

I guess that this can be fixed by correct setting of setSortOrder, but I haven't found one that fits my requirement.

Comment: Have you tried without `setSortOrder()`?

Comment: Yes, it sorts photos by date (I guess) ascending, so the oldest photos are on top.